# iOS app slows down after a few seconds, speeds back up if paused and resumed in debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, performance

First of all, there's not a lot of detail I can offer, so I realize this question may seem incomplete. At this stage, I'm really looking for any ideas. Frankly, I'm just baffled by this one.

I'm building a graphics-heavy app that really maxes out the CPU. CPU utilization on the devices tends to be around 150% according to XCode (I know that sounds weird, it seems to be of a possible 200% because of the device having two cores). I've instrumented the tasks that do the most processing so I can see how long they take in the debug output. Also note that I am compiling with -Ofast (aggressive optimizations), even for debug builds.

Here's the weird thing. About 5-10 seconds into running the CPU intensive mode of the app, everything slows down. It's very visible. Because of my instrumentation, I can see that suddenly everything takes about 3 times as long as it did before. It's pretty uniform across all tasks, and it doesn't speed back up. Here's the really weird thing. If I break execution in the debugger and resume, I get another 5-10 seconds of fast execution before it slows down again.

Looking at the CPU and memory usage reported by XCode, everything stays about the same. The app uses no more than 90MB of memory at any point.

Is there a feature of iOS that slows down CPU intensive apps or underclocks the device to conserve battery life? I realize I'm sharing resources with the OS, but this is behavior I can reliably reproduce every time.

Again, I realize my question is vague, and there's no relevant code I can post. Any ideas about causes or even debugging methods are welcome.

Comment: do you do disk or net io? I can match the behavior to a file copy that is screaming fast - until the caches are full and you are reduced to the real io of the slowest element. Stopping gives the system time to breathe (empty queues and caches) and when you start to run the code again, the same effect will happen.

Comment: That's a really good idea, but unfortunately there is no disk or network I/O happening during this time.

Comment: How hot is the device? Could it be temperature guard?

Comment: Doesn't seem especially hot, but also an interesting idea!

Comment: last one before i give up: cpu cache boundaries: your code requires memory access and runs from cache before the slowdown.. that one is lame becauae it does not really explain the debugger thing.

Comment: @thst, your ideas were really good. I hope you don't think I'm ungrateful. My question was pretty dumb since it was so open ended.

Comment: It may or may not be related, but I just added a SO question that shows CPU slowdown results like this but with Metal buffers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727578/ios-11-cpu-throttling-and-idle-timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you @thst for trying really hard to help me out. My question was kind of dumb since it really could have been anything.

I eventually solved the problem by rendering (via OpenGL, a detail I forgot to include, again showing how bad my question was) only when there is actually a change to the state of the objects and textures being rendered. It used to render at 60FPS all the time.

The app also uses CIDetector to detect faces. I think, but I am not sure, that CIDetector uses the GPU to perform its detection. If so, there might have been some contention for GPU resources. CIDetector blocking on a wait may have caused slowdown throughout the app.

Thanks everyone.